# Regex to search and replace whats inside parenthesis

Tags: regex

We're trying to find text inside parenthesis and replace it with a words. In this case all text inside parenthesis, like `(R:2379; L:28)` etc are to be replaced with `(Receipt No.:2379; Ledger No.:28)`

There's that very same text on the next line that should not be touched (Don't know why it there. This is from an old DOS accounting application).

I came upto `/\([R.]]+\)/g, 'Receipt No.'` but this is harder than I imagined. How can this be done?

```
#Ch. No. 209488 #Rt. Date 12-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2379;L:28)
R:2379;L:28
#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432; L:28)
R:2432; L:28
#Ch. No. 884274 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 19-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2475; L:28)
R:2475; L:28
#Ch. No. 884275 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 24-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2480; L:28)
R:2480; L:28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\(R:(\d+);\s*L:(\d+)\)
```

Replace with `(Receipt No.:$1; Ledger No.:$2)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8WYjk/1/). Details:

- `\(R:` - `(R:` text
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `;` - a `;` char
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `L:` - a  literal `L:` text
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\)`  - a `)` char.

The `$1` is the backreference to Group 1 value and the  `$2` is the backreference to Group 2 value.

Comment: JavaScript: `text = text.replace(/\(R:(\d+);\s*L:(\d+)\)/g, '(Receipt No.:$1; Ledger No.:$2)')`